# Increasing percentage when starting from 0.

Tags: percentages

hello i thought of this question "sally has 0 apples, the next day she has 1 apple what's the percentage increase of apples"?

Does anyone know the answer? just thought of this question. Any number multiplied by 0 makes 0 and so I don't know what the answer is
I hope I'm not missing anything obvious
0 times any n = 0
so I'm not sure what a possible solution to this is

Comment: An infinite increase...

Comment: jean Marie but wouldn't infinity times 0 still be 0?

Comment: percentage increase =(increase /original amount) x 100 %. In this case, the original amount is 0. You can't divide by 0 so the percentage increase is undefined. There is no real number whose name is "infinity."

Comment: @P. Lawrence You are right when you come back to the definition, and I am right in saying that usually in mathematics $1/0$ is conventionally $\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

From a purely physical and non-mathematical perspective, it doesn't make much sense to state that one has "$0$ apples". There is no way to tell what type of object you have none of. Moreover, comparing "nothing" to a finite number of apples may lead one to understand why the answer is just as nonsensical.

Does that reasoning make any sense?